# Proper way of importing multiple large dependencies in Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm working on a project and want to use Lambda to run my code. The thing is I have a lot of dependencies and I'm not sure what the best way to run them is. For example, I use the hugging face `transformers` and `datasets` libraries and also `pytorch` and some others. These files are all super large and there's no way I can fit them in one Layer on Lambda. Right now I'm thinking of splitting it up into different layers, a layer for a dependency. But I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it.

The way I'm getting the zipped files is basically through this tutorial: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/add-external-python-libraries-aws-lambda-using-layers-gabe-olokun/. My disk space is extremely limited as I can't even zip `datasets` and `transformers` together in one file.

From what I read here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/chapter-layers.html it seems like having multiple layers could work. But the example DOES only illustrates two lambda functions pointing to one layer. So I just want some clarification on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> there's no way I can fit them in one Layer on Lambda.

That's why [lambda containers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html) exist and should be used in your case. They give you 10 GB for your dependencies.